# Cant display video, received by gstreamer. No picture is displayed, only solid color is visible

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm trying to learn something about gstreamer and for niw I'm using gstreamer to receive video stream, which is streamed over udp by vlc player. In order to do this, I wrote the following code.

```
playbin = gst_element_factory_make("playbin2", "play");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(playbin), "uri", uri.c_str(), NULL);

bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(playbin));
gst_bus_add_watch(bus, &bus_watcher, NULL);
gst_object_unref(bus);

gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(playbin), GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

The problem is that video is not displayed. The only thing shown if grey(black/green/blue etc) screen. Sometimes it is possible to see some figures moving there. The situation is a bit better with sound. Most of the time it is recognizable. I tried to set properties like "buffer-duration" and "buffer-size" but the only effect I can mention is the improvement of quality of the sound.
And one more thing. I've tried to use usual playbin (meaning not playbin2) and it worked a bit better. At least sound quality increased.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: That seems like C code, so how about adding the C tag?

Comment: What gstreamer version did you use. Does it happen for all kind of files or only a particullar one. Try playing the video in an application like totem that uses gstreamer. Basically, try to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still cant display video, but it's not about errors in program or video file format. I've managed to display the same video, with the same playbin after I broadcasted it over http.

Comment: To grab a broadcast over UDP using playbin2 you want to set the URI to
"udp://0.0.0.0:5000". Replace the 5000 with the port you are broadcasting to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a video sink and an audio sink to your application and have a greater control of what's going on.

[Example 2.1](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html) is a python application that shows to do that.